# Swift Cannot find variable in scope

Tags: swift

Swift giving error that var is not in scope. "Cannot find 'midiManager' in scope" I am not sure how to fix issue

menu.swift

```
struct MainMenuBar: MenuBar {
    public var body: StandardMenuBar {
        StandardMenu(title: "Midi Devices") {
            midiManager.endpoints.outputs.forEach { device in
                TextMenuItem(title: device.name) { _ in
                    print(device.uniqueID)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

midi.swift

```
@objc(ReactNativeMidiModule)
class ReactNativeMidiModule: RCTEventEmitter, NSApplicationDelegate {
  // Create midi manager
  public let midiManager = MIDI.IO.Manager(
    clientName: "MIDIEventLogger",
    model: "ELMC Midi Monitor",
    manufacturer: "ELMC")

  // other code
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`midiManager` is not present inside your `MainMenueBar`. So `midiManager` can not be found. You must need to add `midiManager` inside your `MainMenueBar` structure. Like this -

```
struct MainMenuBar: MenuBar
{
    public let midiManager = MIDI.IO.Manager(clientName: "MIDIEventLogger", model: "ELMC Midi Monitor", manufacturer: "ELMC")
    public var body: StandardMenuBar
    {
        
        StandardMenu(title: "Midi Devices")
        {
            midiManager.endpoints.outputs.forEach { device in
                TextMenuItem(title: device.name) { _ in
                    print(device.uniqueID)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**or**
By creating a common class as-

```
class MidiManager {
    static let midiManager = MIDI.IO.Manager(clientName: "MIDIEventLogger", model: "ELMC Midi Monitor", manufacturer: "ELMC")
}
```

And then use it in both `MainMenuBar` and `ReactNativeMidiModule` as-

```
struct MainMenuBar: MenuBar {
    public let midiManager = MidiManager.midiManager
    public var body: StandardMenuBar {
        StandardMenu(title: "Midi Devices") {
            midiManager.endpoints.outputs.forEach { device in
                TextMenuItem(title: device.name) { _ in
                    print(device.uniqueID)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@objc(ReactNativeMidiModule)
class ReactNativeMidiModule: RCTEventEmitter, NSApplicationDelegate {
  // Create midi manager
  public let midiManager = MidiManager.midiManager

  // other code
}
```

Comment: Is there another way I can recode so that I don't create another instance of a midi client. Currently when I do this it create 2 midi clients

Comment: Yes, you can create another class. Check my updated answer.